# Return a random row without using ID, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, random

I am looking for a better way of doing this:

```
SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id >= (SELECT FLOOR( MAX(id) * RAND()) FROM $tbl_name ) ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;
```

**It is slow and isn't very random, I get the same result every 10 or so query's.**

This selects a random row from the table regardless of its ID.

So far I have this:

```
// Get amount of rows in database
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

// Generate random number
$random_row = rand(1, $num_rows);
```

But I don't know how to get a certain row.

I do not mean

```
SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id = $random_row
```

Because my database has gaps in the ID column so it would sometimes fail.

Has anyone got  script that can get a random result from a MySQL database without replying on IDs and is super fast? (the database contains about 20000 rows)

Comment: Just to add, this is used on a high traffic website, so speed is important.

Comment: After some searching though the comments on the link Adi sent, I have found a decent solution.

    SELECT * FROM $tbl_name T JOIN (SELECT CEIL(MAX(ID)*RAND()) AS ID FROM $tbl_name) AS x ON T.ID >= x.ID LIMIT 1;

Source: http://wanderr.com/jay/order-by-slow/2008/01/30/

Seems to be very fast and very random!

Comment: `// Get amount of rows in database` - as a matter of fact, you are selecting not the amount but ALL the rows with this query. Go figure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching though the comments on the link Adi sent, I have found a decent solution.

```
SELECT * FROM $tbl_name T JOIN (SELECT CEIL(MAX(ID)*RAND()) AS ID FROM $tbl_name) AS x ON T.ID >= x.ID LIMIT 1;
```

Source: wanderr.com/jay/order-by-slow/2008/01/30

Seems to be very fast and very random!

Comment: so, it is more random than order by rand()?

Comment: Yes, when using rand() it returned results near 0 more often and I was receiving the same result every 10 or so query's.

Comment: it is using the same rand() function. it seems you mistaken here

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

20,000 rows isn't really that much, the above should be fast enough.

Comment: I have tried your query and it works, but doesn't seem to be very random, I get the same result every 10 or so querys.

Answer (score 1):

Juhana is right by the book: "ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1", and of course 20k isn1t that much. 
Other option will be with subselects:
SELECT [fields] 
FROM myTable, 
(SELECT FLOOR(MAX(myTable.id) * RAND()) AS randId FROM myTable) AS someRandId 
WHERE myTable.id = someRandId.randId

discussed [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?132,185266,219422#msg-219422)
(please avoid select * when it`s unnecessary)